# How to get the authorization code for the aura component?

Tags: salesforce, integration

how to get the authorization code for the aura component?? struggling to find...
for example : For vf pages we will write code = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code');

what is the procedure to get this code for aura component ?? anyone pls help

I tried many ways.. but getting the null value..